# ubuntu 14.04 desktop amd64 installation fails with kernel panic under vmware

Tags: system-installation, virtualization, vmware

I've just downloaded ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso, created new VM in VMWare Workstation 7.1.6 build-744570 using

- Typical -> I will install the OS later
- Linux / Ubuntu 64-bit

**VM Settings:**

- 2GB virtual RAM
- 20GB virtual HDD
- 1 virtual processor Intel VT x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI
- CD using ISO image I've downloaded
- NAT
- USB
- Sound Card Auto detect
- Display: no 3D Acceleration / Use host setting
  (tried 1 monitor / 1024x768 as well)

Booting and it fails with

```
RIP native_write_cr4
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task!
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Where's the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem persists with 32bit version:

Comment: http://pdebski.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/ubuntu-14-04-desktop-i386-installation-fails-with-kernel-panic-under-vmware/

Comment: @closevoters: 14.04 is on-topic. Do you have VMware tools installed? If yes, did you try easy install? Did you try installing the OS by selecting the ISO first and not later(this may not be the cause but just to try out)?

Comment: @Jobin AFAIK VMWare tools shall be installed in the guest when the guest system is already running. Not sure how to add drivers on the first boot.

Comment: I've solved the problem already some time ago: there was a bug in VMWare causing it to report wrong number of processor cores to the guest (true one instead of guest virtual one set in options). Ubuntu got confused trying to use 4 processor cores while having only one available. After installing patches to the VMWare problem disappeared automagically.

Comment: As the question is closed not sure how I can answer this question so the whole community can benefit. Hence the comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are some boot options.
When you are booting, press any-key (space) then press F6 and try several options.
For me, nolapic option makes ubuntu 14.04 to boot.